# Bootstrap CSS class not applying on dynamic <li>

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a horizontal Menu where I’ve `dropdowns`. I need li’s in the `dropdown-menu` which I’ve commented out dynamically. So I added div and thought of appending the div with dynamic `<li>`’s in jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<li class="dropdown">
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <%-- <li ><a href="Link1">Link1</a></li>
         <li ><a href="Link2">Link2</a></li>
    --%>
    <div id="dvLinks"></div>
   </ul> 
 </li>
```

**jQuery**

```
var invDiv = '';
$.each(result, function (i, value) {
   invDiv += '<li><a href=' + result.href + '>' + Links + '</a></li>'; 
});

$('#dvLinks').append(invDiv);
```

From above, I get the result, but the **class="dropdown-menu" doesn’t apply to these dynamic li’s**. Since `<div>` are not allowed in `<ul>` technically, so I tried below. But this doesn’t give me any result in UI. Please help, where am I going wrong.

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
    <div id="dvLinks"></div> 
  </li>

var invDiv = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';

$.each(result, function (i, value) {
   invDiv += '<li><a href=' + result.href + '>' + Links + '</a></li>'; 
});

invDiv += '</ul>'

$('#dvLinks').append(invDiv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append `LI` string to the `UL` element, you don't need div here:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dvLinks"></ul> 
</li>
```

And JS stays the same, just now `$('#dvLinks')` points to the `UL`:

```
var invLi = '';
$.each(result, function (i, value) {
   invLi += '<li><a href=' + result.href + '>' + Links + '</a></li>'; 
});

$('#dvLinks').append(invLi);
```

Comment: Awesome man!! such a easy solution and my brain didn't work about it.. thanks a TON!! you made my day